# Button not firing function from script outside

Tags: javascript, function, button, jsfiddle

I have this simple code with a button, and a function.

if the function is declared inside `<script>`___`</script>` **then it works**
if the function is declared in it's proper allocated space and **not** in the tags, **then it doesn't work**

how can I make it work from it's proper allocated space for the script.

photos:

[image: foo is declared inside script tags]

and here it doesn't work:
[image: foo is **not** declared inside script tags]

the code:
HTML:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div>

 <input type="button" onclick="foo();" value="hell">


 </div>
 </body>
 <html>
```

Javascript:

```
function foo(some)
{
  alert("he123l");
};
```

how can I fix this?

another thing:
I set the load type of the javascript to:  `No wrap - in <body>`

Comment: Could you provide a link to the js-fiddles instead of just screenshots?

Comment: works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/jkpvjj27/1/  i also used no wrap-in <body>...

Comment: I feel you're mistaken. If you had set the load type to `No Wrap - in <Body>`, the example will work, just as Stefan F points out.

Comment: Instead of screenshots of (or links to) jsfiddles, why not just use Stack Overflow's built-in [Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) feature?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: besides now it's working, what fixed it was: I added the button not as an "input" but as a <button onclick="foo()"> then clicked it and it fired. then I changed it again to be an input and now it works as normal. Don't know why I had to go through the normal button tag

Comment: There is not functional difference between an `<INPUT type="button">` and `<BUTTON>` elements when it comes to applying an `onClick` listener. It's just syntactic sugar. Both should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the function before call.
if you do:

```
<script>
function foo(some)
{
  alert("he123l");
};
</script>
 <div>

 <input type="button" onclick="foo();" value="hell">


 </div>
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the *"Load Type"*.

Set it to:

> ```
> No wrap - in <body>
> ```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Here's the [JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/mhg35ae4/).

Comment: thanks man, but I wrote that I already did that and still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers here.
what fixed it at last was to change the code for a minute from:

```
<input type="button" onclick="foo();" value="hell">
```

to

```
<button onclick="foo()">
```

and then click the burron which worked fine and fired the function.
and then change it back to:

```
<input type="button" onclick="foo();" value="hell">
```

and now it works fine. don't know why :/